# Meaning of the expression "2.1 kids"

Tags: meaning, idioms, expressions

What does it mean to say, "Everyone in this city has 2.1 kids"? Is this an idiom?

Comment: Something to do with a place liking goat meat? Or goat milk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the people in the city is stereotypically average-like, with a humorous twist.

Famililes in a region may have 2.1 kids by average. Saying that each familiy literally have 2.1 kids implies that they are average-like to absurdity.

Answer (score 2):

It's an ironic expression of an average as if it were an actual number.

Answer (score 0):

## 2.1 Kids: Stable Population

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBS6f-JVvTY

PS: Not necessarily reflecting my personal views.

Comment: I have a feeling that someone is stalking me and voting down everything I say without bothering with a comment. Very cowardly.

Answer (score 0):

It's a phrase in common use to mean a stereotypically average family.

There was a situation comedy on British TV a few years back called "2.4 Children" which got its title from the average size of a British family (family sizes vary from country to country). They obviously didn't have 2.4 children, unless you count the Dad acting childish 40% of the time, but the title was meant to imply that the family were average in every way.