# What's the difference in saying "the average family" vs. "the family average"?

Tags: phrases, word-order

Consider these two sentences:

> A Scranton family has an average of 2.1 children.
>   The average Scranton family has 2.1 children.

I've seen both used. The first one seems reasonable, but the second 
one seems wrong because you're applying average to *family*, not to 
numbers.

To me, saying "the Jones are an average family" seems legitimate, but  if the Jones have 2.1 children, they're anything but average.

Is the second sentence grammatically correct? Is it understood to mean 
the same as the first sentence?

Inspired by the question, [Meaning of the expression "2.1 kids"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15250/meaning-of-the-expression-2-1-kids).

Answer (score 3):

As you pointed out, the two sentences would typically be interpreted as having the same meaning.

> A Scranton family has an average of
>   2.1 children.
>   The average Scranton family has 2.1
>   children.

The prototypical (average) family has 2.1 children.  "The average family" in this case is a non-existent family, one whose properties are *all* equal to the statistical mean of the implied domain.  This is a construct used for some statistical analysis.

> The Jones are an average family.

The use of "average family" in this case means that this *specific* family is not an extraordinary case.  Their properties are probably *close* to the statistical mean.  However this is very much dependent on context.  Perhaps the Jones are average with respect to income but not necessarily number of children.  Using this phrase would not indicate that the Jones family has *exactly* 2.1 children.

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence, *average* refers to the the result obtained by adding together all the children in Scranton, and dividing this total with the number of families in Scranton.
In the second sentence, *average family* means *an ordinary family*.

Both sentences are grammatically correct.

Comment: As kiamlaluno points out, both sentences are grammatically correct and with different meanings. However, 'an average of 2.1 children' makes sense, because it's a calculated value. In the second sentence, the 'typical' Scranton family is said to have '2.1 children', which is not possible in reality. It's a subtle difference.