# What does "2.2 kids" mean?

Tags: meaning, numbers

The context: Doctors, attorneys, steel
plant executives, dentists, and professional football players lived there with their
adoring wives and their 2.2 kids.

On face value it has something to do with the education but there is not much information.

Comment: Numbers may vary but the meaning is the same: average. Does this answer your question? [Meaning of the expression "2.1 kids"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15250/meaning-of-the-expression-2-1-kids)

Comment: Very probably a statistical number associated to a group where there are "2.2" children per family (10 families and 22 children in all, for example).

Comment: Seems like I should've broadened the context: 
"In 1981, Williamsville offered the
tastiest real estate in Buffalo, New York. Leafy and friendly, its safe streets were
dotted with dainty homes filled with model citizens. Doctors, attorneys, steel
plant executives, dentists, and professional football players lived there with their
adoring wives and their 2.2 kids. Cars were new, roads swept, possibilities
endless. We’re talking about a living, breathing American Dream."

Now I think the idea is about superiority of the parents in terms of social status, thus the greater status of kids.

Comment: The number does not reflect status, only math. Perfectly "adoring" wives and the perfect number of children. Note that all citizens have wives, not spouses.

Comment: Like the duplicate says, it is not literally 2.2 kids- It is not 2 kids who have a status 10% better. It is an average for the country. And this place was so stereotypically ideal that they each had the exact average number of kids. (Not really- it is a joke.)

Comment: in the Eighties in would more likely have been "two and a half kids" (written out). I can see "2.1" and "2.2" in ads from then, but the book hits for the fully-written-out option is much higher. It also was more natural to say.

Comment: Expressions similar to this are fairly common.  It's simply saying that the community being described tends to have families with a small number of kids, and other features representing a healthy family life.

Comment: There was a British sitcom called *2 Point 4 Children*, which had the same idea of an average domestic setting but different figures (maybe a UK average?).